Fourier transform of real exponential
I'm currently reading Zworski's semiclassical analysis and have some question regarding the following example:


In the second equality, I verified the computations by expanding the inner products, and it seems like conjugate symmetry is not used. Just expanding the exponentiated expression after the second equality, I get $$ -1/2 \langle Qx, x\rangle  $$ since the middle terms cancel each other out and the last two terms also cancel each other out. Could somebody please verify this?
In the third equality, it's not clear to me why the domain of integration is still $\mathbb{R}^n$. Should it not be $\mathbb{R}^n \times \{iQ^{-1}\xi\}$?

Thanks!

The value of the expression inside the exponential to the right of the second equality is always real while the expression inside the exponential to the right of the first equality will not always be real. So if the equality holds, you cannot obtain it from only manipulating the inner product. As it appears to be unclear how to fix this approach, I suggest taking a look at the approach here and see if you can modify that to obtain a proof.
